# How to use an custom image as button in jquery mobile split-btn-list

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can i replace the standard icons with my custom image as button in jquery mobile [Split buttons](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview/)-List

I am on a function to add new items to my listview automatically, but the code reaches the html different: my image always diapers and i get the custom arrowIcon.

How it should look like:
[image: How it should be]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom icon for jQM with some css:

```
.ui-icon-customtrash:after {
    background-image: url("http://www.megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/60/256/industry-trash-2-icon.png");
    background-position: 3px 3px;
    background-size: 90%;

    background-color: transparent;
    height: 34px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

Then in the listview, either use `data-split-icon="customtrash"` on the `<UL>` element if all split icons are the same image, or on individual `<LI>`, add `data-icon="customtrash"` to the split icon anchor.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/oqvyp35m/2/)**